# PHP: date function to get month of the current date

Tags: php, datetime

I want to be able to figure out the month of the current date variable. I'm ex vb.net and the way to do it there is just `date.Month`. How do I do this in PHP?

Thanks,

Jonesy

I used `date_format($date, "m"); //01, 02..12`

This is what I wanted, question now is how do I compare this to an int since `$monthnumber = 01` just becomes `1`

Comment: Just thinking what's the +1 in this question...

Comment: please see my edit for your second question.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

See http://php.net/date

`date('m')`  or `date('n')` or `date('F')` ...

**Update**

> *m*  Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros    **01 through 12**
>
> *n*  Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros  **1 through 12**
>
> *F*  Alphabetic representation of a month  **January through December**

....see the docs link for even more options.

Answer (score 93):

What does your "data variable" look like? If it's like this:

```
$mydate = "2010-05-12 13:57:01";
```

You can simply do:

```
$month = date("m",strtotime($mydate));
```

For more information, take a look at [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

**EDIT:**

To compare with an int, just do a `date_format($date,"n");` which will give you the month without leading zero.

Alternatively, try one of these:

```
if((int)$month == 1)...
if(abs($month) == 1)...
```

Or something weird using ltrim, round, floor... but date_format() with "n" would be the best.

Comment: thanks i used date_format($date, "m") to get 01, 02..12. I've updated my question though because this has given me another question.

Answer (score 9):

```
$unixtime = strtotime($test);
echo date('m', $unixtime); //month
echo date('d', $unixtime); 
echo date('y', $unixtime );
```

Answer (score 7):

as date_format uses the same format as date ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php ) the "Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros" is a lowercase n .. so

```
echo date('n'); // "9"
```

Answer (score 6):

As it's not specified if you mean the system's current date or the date held in a variable, I'll answer for latter with an example.

```
<?php
$dateAsString = "Wed, 11 Apr 2018 19:00:00 -0500";

// This converts it to a unix timestamp so that the date() function can work with it.
$dateAsUnixTimestamp = strtotime($dateAsString);

// Output it month is various formats according to http://php.net/date

echo date('M',$dateAsUnixTimestamp);
// Will output Apr

echo date('n',$dateAsUnixTimestamp);
// Will output 4

echo date('m',$dateAsUnixTimestamp);
// Will output 04
?>
```

Comment: @Zaid Bin Khalid for pointing out I mixed up the formatting parameters M and m

Answer (score 0):

To compare with an int do this:

```
<?php
$date = date("m");
$dateToCompareTo = 05;
if (strval($date) == strval($dateToCompareTo)) {
    echo "They are the same";
}
?>
```