# PHP - number of month from date

Tags: php, date, format

I'm trying to get the number of a month from a date using this:

```
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2014-05-04'));  
$Month = date('n', $newDate);
echo $Month;
```

It returns 1 (this is January...) How is this possible? It should return 0.

I used the date format because of that thread:

[PHP: date function to get month of the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768072/php-date-function-to-get-month-of-the-date)

I hope somebody can help me.

Thanks in advance

shivan

Comment: `$newDate` is a `string`, whereas 2nd parameter of `date()` should be `int` (timestamp)

Comment: $Month = date('n', strtotime($newDate));

Comment: I'm curious why you're expecting 0?  Because you think it should be the first number in a list?  PHP returns the month number that anyone would recognize. `date('n')` = 1, `date('m')` = 01

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Month = date('m', strtotime('2014-05-04'));`

you can get the month like this

Answer (score 0):

For datetime operation you should use **[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)** class in PHP

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-05-04');
echo $date->format('n');
```