# How to save month name in mysql (eg: January 2020 instead of 2020-01)?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to insert into MySQL as January 2021 - April 2021 using the form as shown in the image. But when I save it is inserted into MySQL as 2021-01 - 2021-04. How to save input type=month as month name? I have searched for the solutions but the solutions did not fit my need.

[image]

```
<th class="td-info">Semester semasa:</th>
<td>
    <input type="month" name="startSem" required> - <input type="month" name="finishSem" required>
    <p style="color: gray">eg: Januari 2020 - Mei 2021</p>
</td>
```

In PHP I create a new variable to combine two input type=month

```
$currentSem = $_POST['startSem'] . " - " . $_POST['finishSem'];
```

In MySQL, I use varchar instead of DATE

[image]

Comment: Don't. use DATE types and store values 2021-01-01 for that month. Use your PHP to format the date however you want when you use it. The structured form allows SQL to use this efficiently.

Comment: Is the purpose of saving the month _name_ for localization? By default, PHP saves month as numbers because that's the most raw format you can have a month in (and it's the most efficient in MySQL in that format). If you specifically need the name of the month, I suggest you use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768072/php-date-function-to-get-month-of-the-current-date before saving. Or better yet, save in the default format (numbers), but on output back to the user you can use `date()` to get the name again.

Comment: this [comment of @David Storey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648314/8134014) could help you

Comment: Thank you for all the answer but some of the answers get me confused as I'm new to PHP. I will study all the answers provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code to format the date and combine both dates and save `$combineDate` variable in database.

```
$startSem = $_POST['startSem'];
$finishSem = $_POST['finishSem'];
$changeDateFormatStartSem = date('F Y', strtotime($_POST['startSem']));
$changeDateFormatfinishSem = date('F Y', strtotime($_POST['finishSem']));
echo $combineDate = $changeDateFormatStartSem." - ".$changeDateFormatfinishSem;  //output January 2021 - April 2021
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I managed to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

use this as example

```
$date = $your_variable_for_date;
echo date('F Y', strtotime($date));
```

see this as reference:
[image]

Comment: I hope this answer will help you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65696429/14969950 the answer of Talk2Nit completes what you need :)

Comment: I used your answer as reference before Talk2Nit answer my question. Thank you :)

Comment: That's great dude! :)